# Laravel replace primary key with hashids for all get

Tags: php, laravel, string-hashing

Im using laravel 4.2 and I want to use hashids instead of primary key in urls. Its easy to use with a single record. If I use eager loading I need to loop through all models and replace the primary keys with hash ids.

For example.
For every post I need to change the post_id with a hashid.
For every comment of the post I have to do the same.
For every user of the comment and so on..
Can I extend the model to return hashid by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can extend your model with [mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators). Place this method into your models, or even better into your base model which all of your models should extend.

```
public function getHashidAttribute()
{
    return your_hash_function($this->attributes['id']);
}
```

After that you would get `hashid` attribute on your models like so `$post->hashid`, `$comment->hashid` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route::bind method to specify how exactly the models should be resolved from the URL segments like below.

```
Route::bind('post', function($value)
{
    return Post::where('hashid', $value)->first();
});
```

Now Laravel knows how to resolve the Eloquent Model if you use route like this

```
/admin/{post}/edit
```

Comment: This will only work for single record. It wont work with eager loading.